# Unix command equivalent on powershell

Tags: powershell, unix

Unix command example, what is the equivalent on powershell?

```
if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you want an equivalent of a Unix command, but your question isn't clear what platform you need the equivalent command for. If you need a Windows answer, this is pretty close:

```bsh
$windowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$windowsSecurityPrincipal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new($windowsID)
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

if ( -not $windowsSecurityPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole)) {
    Write-Host "Please run as an administrator."
    exit
}
```

In the past I've had self-elevating scripts that began like so:

```bsh
# ##########################################
# Determine if we have Administrator rights
Write-Host 'Checking user permissions... '
$windowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$windowsSecurityPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($windowsID)
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

If (!($windowsSecurityPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))) {
    Write-Warning 'Current user does not have Administrator rights'
    Write-Host 'Attempting to copy files to temporary location and restarting script'

    # Get random file name
    Do {
        $temp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath() + [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()
    } Until (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath "$temp"))

    # Create directory
    Write-Host 'Creating temp directory... ' -NoNewLine
    New-Item -Path "$temp" -ItemType 'Directory' | Out-Null
    Write-Host 'done.'

    # Copy script to directory
    Write-Host 'Copying script to temp directory... ' -NoNewLine
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$($myInvocation.MyCommand.Path)" "$temp" | Out-Null
    Write-Host 'done.'
    $newScript = "$($temp)\$($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    
    # Start new script elevated
    Write-Host 'Starting script as administrator... ' -NoNewLine
    $adminProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $adminProcess.Filename = ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()).Path
    $adminProcess.Arguments = " -File `"$newScript`""
    $adminProcess.Verb = 'runas'
    
    Try {
        [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($adminProcess) | Out-Null
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error 'Could not start process'
        Exit 1
    }
    Write-Host 'done.'
    
    Exit 0
} 

# Begin script code here
```

That code is pretty old. I think I wrote it for Powershell 2 or 3. It should still function, although it's not the prettiest code anymore.

Comment: Do you mean: [Find-Module -Name '*sudo*' | Select-Object -Property Name, Description]
                                                                         
Sudo    Use functionality similar to sudo in PowerShell. GitHub: https://github.com/pldmgg/Sudo
PSSudo  Function for executing programs with adminstrative privileges                          
PwrSudo Implements Unix/sudo (Execute-Elevated) for powershell

Comment: @postanote If you have an alternate answer, please post it as such. No need to be snarky.

Comment: What!?!?!. What was snarky about my comment? It's a simple response pointing to resources that are potentials for the OP's use case.

Comment: @wallybh answer's far superior to this and should be marked as the correct.

Comment: @BrunoSalvino That answer only works in a *nix environment or one that has some flavor of coreutils installed. OP clearly needs a native Windows equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

if you are running powershell on linux you can write something like this:

```
 if ((id -u) -ne 0) {
     write-host "Please run as root"
     exit
 }
```

if you are using powershell on windows, use the statement [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-5.1). That way the script will run only if the user is an administrator.  Example:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

write-host "This is an administrator"
```